# executeQuery() returns empty ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm creating a simple app which uses JDBC to get data from MySQL. I use a dao to get data from the database. All but one are working fine (code is the same for all DAOs). Also I'm committing INSERT and UPDATE methods manually.

Workbench returns valid result even if I set isolation level read committed manually.

JDBCSessionDao create method:

```
public void create(Session session) throws SQLException{
        try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_SESSION)){
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            LocalTime start = session.getStartTime();
            LocalTime end = session.getEndTime();

            System.out.println(start + ", " + end);
            System.out.println(Time.valueOf(start) + ", " + Time.valueOf(end));

            ps.setTime(1, Time.valueOf(start));
            ps.setTime(2, Time.valueOf(end));
            ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(session.getDate()));
            ps.setLong(4, session.getMovieId());

            ps.executeUpdate();

            conn.commit();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            conn.rollback();
        }
    }
```

JDBCSessionDao findByDate method

```
public List<Session> findByDate(LocalDate date) {
    List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
    SessionMapper mapper = new SessionMapper();

    try(PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_BY_DATE_ORDER_BY_TIME_ASC)){
        ps.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(date));

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        System.out.println(rs.getFetchSize());

        while(rs.next()){
            Session s = mapper.extractFromResultSet(rs);
            sessions.add(s);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return sessions;
}
```

Query:

```
String SELECT_BY_DATE_ORDER_BY_TIME_ASC = "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_date=? ORDER by start_time ASC";
```

JDBCDaoFactory getConnection() method:

```
private Connection getConnection(){
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cinemajee?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }
    catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Query result in workbench:
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9yCl.jpg)

Comment: I'd suggest using `LocalDate` using `setObject(1, localDataValue)` instead of using `java.sql.Date` with `setDate`. Possibly you are running afoul of 'off by one' errors with dates caused by confusing definition of `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: You're sure the date isn't in format String in your db. Also try to print the date to see if its ``yyyy-MM-dd``

Comment: Thank you guys, i've found the problem. I forgot to change column names in my SessionMapper class (previous i was using camel case, now i'm using snake case). Such stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot to change column names in SessionMapper, they were written in camel case (e.g. sessionId) but my db columns is in snake case (e.g. session_id).

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the query in your code. Perhaps the `session_date` parameter isn't working. So change from this:

```
"SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_date=? ORDER by start_time ASC"'
```

to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER by start_time ASC LIMIT 5"'
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is none of "find*" methods is working, here is test result: [tests](https://imgur.com/l19kq1J), all tests are check variables for emptiness (two lists and one Optional).